# Configure Google Maps SDK for iOS CocoaPod to Exclude armv7s Slice

Tags: xcode, configuration, google-maps-sdk-ios, cocoapods, xcode5

As the [Google Maps SDK for iOS instructions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#adding_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios_to_your_project) state, the `armv7s` architecture should be removed from *Architectures* in the *Build Settings* tab. However, I feel like there should be some way of configuring the Google Maps `podspec` so that this is done automatically when running `pod install`. Particularly with CocoaPods 0.21.0.rc1, though, I'm not quite sure where to do this, as not only can you change the *Architectures* in your project's *Build Settings*, but you can also change it for each of the Pods project's targets.

This question has two parts:

1. Where specifically should `armv7s` be removed in a project built using CocoaPods 0.21.0.rc1?
2. How can the Google Maps SDK for iOS's `podspec` be changed so that all of this is done automatically on `pod install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to be done on the end target, i.e. your app target. In CocoaPods we try to not touch the user’s project anymore than absolutely necessary, this is currently outside of that scope.

You could probably make it work from a post install hook by manipulating the user’s project directly, but that would get very fragile and likely break in the future.

Even though I’m not a fan of post install messages, in this case it might be appropriate. In your podspec, do something like the following:

```
s.post_install do |library_representation|
  puts "[!] The Google Maps SDK requires you to only build your application for armv7.".orange
  puts "    For more info see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#adding_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios_to_your_project".orange
end
```

(This is untested code btw.)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. As for the first part of the question, though, should `armv7s` only be removed from the project's *Build Settings*, or should it be removed from the Pods-Google-Maps-iOS-SDK target as well?

Comment: As I understand it, it should only be needed on the user’s project, not the Pods target.

Comment: Is that still the case?